# Entity Framework Doesn't create a new proxy Why?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, entity, relation

i've got some trouble with EF (6.0.0)

here is the code

```
var Answer = new TicketAnswer();
Answer.Answer = "hello";
Answer.TicketId = 20;
Answer.ConfirmDate = DateTime.Now;
db.TicketAnswer.Add(Answer);
db.SaveChanges();

AnswerId = Answer.ID;

db.TicketAnswer.Where(x=> x.ID == AnswerId).FirstOrDefault();
```

after that , when im trying to get the db.TicketAnswer with the same Id of the Answer (which is new created) EF returning with TicketAnswer class (not a proxy) and i cant access to Ticket class over that (Ticket Property is null even TicketId is not null and there is Ticket on the db which Id = 20 , there is not problem with relations) , but when i change my query to :

```
var a = db.TicketAnswer.Where(x => x.ID == 225).FirstOrDefault();
```

EF returning back with System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies_ASDGAFD... and i can access to Ticket class.

All i want is , reach Ticket class over TicketAnswer class , What should i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your navigation property has not yet loaded for the newly added entity in that context. To load it you must:

```
 var ticketAnswer = db.TicketAnswer.Include(ta => ta.Ticket).Where(x=> x.ID == AnswerId).FirstOrDefault();
```

or better:

```
 var ticketAnswer = db.TicketAnswer.Include(ta => ta.Ticket).Single(ta=> ta.Id == answerId);
```

One may ask "Then why the other entity (with Id == 225) is loaded *without* using this .Inlcude thing?"

The answer is: That entity was added surely by and other run session, using an other db context instance. So that entity in not in the cache of the current db context instance. When asking for it, EF will load it, and navigation properties are available without explicit Include. However the freshly added entity is *in* the cache, with no navigation properties. Simple asking for it using where will give you back the very same instance you've added. Note: not just very same entity: the very same *instance*.

To navigate multiple hops in your entity graph you can use:

```
.Include("Ticket.User") // In case if the Ticket entity has a navigation property called 'User'
```

Comment: i ask my question incorrectly :/  , that Id=225 is the newest Id (same of the AnswerId) and it doesn't matter. The problem is about runtime i guess.

Comment: and you absolutely right , i must refresh my context. by the way EF version is 6.0.0 and Include function requires string parameter not a delegate. but Include method not solving my problem because i need to use Ticket.User.SomeUserProperties , and when im use db.TicketAnswer.Include("Ticket") , i cant navigate User class same way and when i try to Include("Ticket").Include("User") it says that User does not belong to TicketAnswer class.... its very complicated. when im use  db = new Context(); after the db.SaveChanges() , the problem is solved. but it not a good solution...

Comment: Well that 225 is the very same as answerId _was_ in the _previous_ run session. Then you edited your source typed 225 and launched a _new_ run session. You asked your question correctly, the was no misunderstanding.

Comment: About accessing Ticket.User, please see my edited answer